# fill web page text boxes and submit automatically by web browser control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

i fill web page  text boxes by web browser control  but after filling them  the entrance button stay disable ...when i fill them by keyboard(not automatically) the button activated and i can go next page...i searched in web to solve this problem and i think my code is true ...can you help to solve this problem

```
    Dim a1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim a2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim a3 As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim a4 As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim a5 As String = TextBox5.Text


    For Each link As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

        If link.GetAttribute("name") = "firstName" Then

            link.SetAttribute("value", a1)


        End If

        If link.GetAttribute("name") = "lastName" Then

            link.SetAttribute("value", a2)


        End If

        If link.GetAttribute("name") = "userName" Then

            link.SetAttribute("value", a3)


        End If

        If link.GetAttribute("name") = "password" Then

            link.SetAttribute("value", a4)


        End If


        If link.GetAttribute("name") = "cellPhoneNo" Then

            link.SetAttribute("value", a5)


        End If



    Next
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for these buttons?

Comment: <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="Login()" disabled="disabled"> ورود مشتری</button>

Comment: i dont want click button automatically  i only want fill text boxes and click button by mouse  but after filling them aytomatically the button  is not activated and i cannot go to nest pages

Comment: I think the html from the inputs is what they're asking for, to make sure you're selecting the right attributes...not the button's

Comment: evan after  filling textboxes  automatically  i cut textes again paste them  by mouse  and  entrance button be activated but  time is important for me  and i want  click button  handedly(by mouse)  after  set input data(automatically)

Comment: Are you using Angular as well?  I see the ng references.

Comment: i could not what you ment?

Comment: the html code for one of textboxes are:<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" placeholder="نام" ng-model="firstName" maxlength="300" required="">

Comment: <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control  ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" placeholder="نام خانوادگی" ng-model="lastName" maxlength="300" required="">

Comment: <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control floating-label ng-pristine ng-empty ng-valid-validnationcode ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" maxlength="10" ng-model="userName" placeholder="کد ملی " required="" validnationcode="">

Comment: <input name="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="password" placeholder="شماره شناسنامه" required="">

Comment: <input type="text" name="cellPhoneNo" class="form-control  ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" placeholder="تلفن همراه" ng-model="cellPhoneNo" maxlength="11" required="">

Comment: can anyone help me.....i really need to solve this problem?????????

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
link.SetAttribute("value", a1)
```

try using

```
link.value = a1
```

Do this for all fields

Comment: unfortunately the value property is not available for html elements